# In which of the pipelining stages are L1 caches accessed?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I am reading about caches and I'm not sure when we access L1 caches (Fetch, Decode, memory or write back)?

Comment: Which L1? I or D? Which architecture? Probably Fetch for the L1I and Memory for the L1D.

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline, or a modern x86 like Haswell (https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/6/)?  I assume classic RISC based on your names for stages.  Are you considering a CPU with a store queue to hide stalls for cache miss stores?